# Yii2 How to update cell with a db migrate file

Tags: yii2

I need to update a row, but I cant find any example of this on the web on how to do this with a yii migrate file.

```
Table = pages
Column = name
Value = newsletter-index
Slug = this value we need to update
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I undestand correctly this should be it. It updates `slug` column with new value for the rows where column `name` is `newsletter-index`.

```
public function up()
{
    $this->update('pages', ['slug' => 'new value here'], ['name' => 'newsletter-index']);
}
```